# When import docx in python3.3 I have error ImportError: No module named 'exceptions'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

when I import `docx` I have this error:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docx-0.2.4-py3.3.egg/docx.py", line 30, in <module>
    from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning
ImportError: No module named 'exceptions'
```

How to fix this error (`python3.3`, docx 0.2.4)?

Comment: The `exceptions` module does not exist in Python 3 (exceptions defined there were added to `__builtin__` anyway). Looks like the conversion of DocX to Python 3 is not complete yet.

Answer (score 336):

If you are using python 3x don't do `pip install docx` instead go for

```
pip install python-docx
```

It is compatible with python 3.x

Official Documentation available here: https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/

Comment: this solved my issue , updated official  link in the document

Comment: Worked for me, with Python 3.7.3.

Comment: ... and to remove `docx`, you can do `pip uninstall docx` first to keep it clean!

Answer (score 37):

When want to use `import docx`, be sure to install **python-docx**, *not **docx***.You can install the module by running `pip install python-docx`.

The installation name **docx** is for a different module
However,

when you are going to import the python-docx module, 
you’ll need to run
`import docx`, not `import python-docx`.

*if still you want to use docx module then*:

First of all, you will need to make sure that the **docx** module is installed.
If not then simply run `pip install docx`. 
If it shows '*requirement already satisfied*'
then the solution is :

1. Go to the library to find **docx.py** file,
   you'll need to go to directory where you installed python then \Lib\site-packages\ and find **docx.py** file
2. Open **docx.py** file in text editor and find this code

   ```
   from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning
   ```
3. Replace the above code with

```
try:
    from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning
except ImportError:
    pass
```

4. Save the file
5. Now you can run **import docx** module in Python 3.x without any problem

Answer (score 20):

1. Uninstall docx module with `pip uninstall docx`
2. Download `python_docx-0.8.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl` file from [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)
3. Run `pip install python_docx-0.8.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl` to reinstall docx.

This solved the above import error smoothly for me.

Answer (score 16):

If you're using python 3.x, Make sure you have both **python-docx** & **docx** installed.

Installing python-docx :

```
pip install python-docx
```

Installing docx :

```
pip install docx
```

Answer (score 10):

You may be install `docx`, not `python-docx`

You can see this for install `python-docx`

http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/install.html#install

Comment: The exceptions module not found is the error that appears when installing the wrong library

Answer (score 8):

> In Python 3 exceptions module was removed and all standard exceptions were moved to builtin module. Thus meaning that there is no more need to do explicit import of any standard exceptions.

[copied from](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/hCqNuEQKwso)

Answer (score 5):

pip install python-docx

this worked for me, try installing with admin mode

Answer (score 3):

The problem, as was noted previously in comments, is the docx module was not compatible with Python 3.  It was fixed in this pull-request on github: https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx/pull/67

Since the exception is now built-in, the solution is to not import it.

```diff
docx.py
@@ -27,7 +27,12 @@
 except ImportError:
     TAGS = {}

-from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning
+# Handle PendingDeprecationWarning causing an ImportError if using Python 3
+try:
+    from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning
+except ImportError:
+    pass
+
 from warnings import warn

 import logging
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it work with python3.

```
                     sudo pip3 install python-docx
```

This installation worked for me in Python3 without any further additions.

```
             python3
             >> import docx
```

PS: Note that the 'pip install python-docx' or apt-get python3-docx are not useful.

Comment: You can't really say 'pip install python-docx' is not useful, as it does exactly the same as the pip3 command if you are in a python3 environment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after installing docx module, got a bunch of errors regarding docx, .oxml and lxml...seems that for my case the package was installed in this folder:

`C:\Program Files\Python3.7\Lib\site-packages`

and I moved it one step back, to:

`C:\Program Files\Python3.7\Lib`

and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

python imports exceptions module by itself
comment out import line. it worked for me.

Comment: They don't have an "import" line (an "import exceptions" line). An external module does. That's the problem. Well, since the question is 8 years old, it is more than probable that that bug in that module has been solved for now. Please, when answering to old question, be sure to understand both questions and existing answer, and explain how your answer bring a new information that was not given at the time.

Answer (score 0):

For 2024, besides installing `python-docx` package, I have to install libreoffice in MacOS.

```
brew install --cask libreoffice
```