# python, docx, what would have been error in my code while using docx module

Tags: python, python-docx

I am getting following error "line 30, in 
    from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'"

I have imported docx module, yet I am getting this error

import docx

doc = docx.Document()
doc.add_paragraph(input(''))

Comment: do you have a file called docx.py?

Comment: No .. I do not have any such file in my entire project

Comment: It seems you are trying to use a python 2.x package in python 3.x https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765313/when-import-docx-in-python3-3-i-have-error-importerror-no-module-named-excepti

Answer (score 0):

It seems you installed `docx` which is not maintained anymore and you should instead install the `python-docx` package.

Comment: PyChram suggesting to install docx module.. I have installed python-docx module using pip in Python directory but invain

Comment: I ran your code without the error with ``python-docx`` and got the error with ``docx``.
Do you have both ``docx`` and ``python-docx`` installed? If it is the case, try to uninstall ``docx``.

Comment: nope.. I have uninstalled docx module explicitly.. though error persists

Comment: Which version of Python and ``python-docx`` do you have?

Comment: Python 3.7 .. installed python-docx through pip

Comment: For information, I have Python 3.7.3 and ``pip freeze`` gives me ``lxml==4.4.1`` and ``python-docx==0.8.10``. I don't have the error. Maybe ``docx`` is still loaded in your interpreter.