# save text to a docx file python

Tags: python, docx

I have a structured text on python. I want to save it to a docx file.

Something like

```
text = "A simple text\n Structured"

with open('docx_file.docx', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Answer (score 9):

Check [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package:

```
from docx import Document

document = Document()
document.add_heading('A simple text', level=1)
document.add_paragraph('some more text ... ')

document.save('docx_file.docx')
```

Comment: it is possible to save the full text (already containing meta characters) all at once without compromising the format? Or do I have to manually save each paragraph

Comment: if you already have the preformed text already to go, try just writing it to a file. You could also write any data you wanted to the document variable, extract the text from that, and then modify the headers.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'

Comment: @Anonymous it's the known problem with docx and python3, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44233838/356838

Answer (score 0):

A docx file is not a plain text file, so unless you want to not use a library for this, I recommend https://grokonez.com/python/how-to-read-write-word-docx-files-in-python-docx-module.
Unless you need to use a "fancy" format like docx, I would recommend just writing plain text to a txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I have used to save a text string to a word document.

```
newfile = open("Result.doc", "w+")
newfile.write("Hello World!")
newfile.close()
```