# Why is "import docx" not working in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I have installed Pyhton-docx through `pip3 isntall python-docx` on my mac terminal.
When I import it into python with `import docx` it always gives me an import error.
Why is this so?

Comment: Please provide the error message that you receive when you try to import "docx".

Comment: The answer here may help you solve the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765313/when-import-docx-in-python3-3-i-have-error-importerror-no-module-named-excepti

Comment: If you have multiple python installations on your computer, `pip3` might have installed to an unintended environment. If you do have multiple installations, I recommend installing with `python3 -m pip install python-docx`, where `python3` is whichever python installation you want to use.