# Can't use modules I downloaded from third party in python 3.9

Tags: python

I am new to python but recently downloaded a module from a third party called docx.
When I try to import the library I get the following error:

> no module named docx.

I am unable to use any module from site_packages with the same error, however when I look at the libraries in PyCharm the modules are there. I have tried fixing common errors like checking the file path etc. but still can't resolve the issue.

[image: cant use docx module I recently installed or any module from site_packages]

Comment: Is PyCharm using the expected version of Python? Oftentimes the problem is PyCharm is looking in a different place. Try running your code with `import sys`, `print(sys.executable)` both in PyCharm and at the command line, and you may see two different installs.

Comment: I can't read the blue hand written text on dark grey background.

Comment: Hi there thank you for the advice, I've made sure that only one version of python is installed . The blue text highlights the error which is "no module named Docx " still trying to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that error was about docx module ?
When I've installed docx and tried to import it, I got exception that another its dependency is missing.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'

And here is the old discussion abut this problem.
[When import docx in python3.3 I have error ImportError: No module named 'exceptions'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765313/when-import-docx-in-python3-3-i-have-error-importerror-no-module-named-excepti)

In my case pip installed version 0.2.4. I've uninstalled it and installed "python-docx"

> pip3 install python-docx

docs: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html

and now I can import docx.

Comment: Hi there thank you for the advice , i've tried to uninstall pip and install docx but still not working will have to eliminate other possibilites