# Why am I getting this ImportError when trying to import docx in the Terminal?

Tags: python

I'm learning Python at the moment, and after installing the docx module, I keep getting this error when trying to import it in the Terminal:

> import docx
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/Users/trevorstathatos/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/docx/**init**.py", line 14, in 
> from docx.parts.document import DocumentPart
> File "/Users/trevorstathatos/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/docx/parts/document.py", line 7, in 
> from docx.document import Document
> File "/Users/trevorstathatos/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/docx/document.py", line 10, in 
> from docx.section import Section, Sections
> File "/Users/trevorstathatos/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/docx/section.py", line 7, in 
> from collections import Sequence
> ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/collections/**init**.py)

When trying to import it to my Mu Editor, I get this error:

import docx

~/Library/Application Support/mu/mu_venv-38-20211212-105811/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docx.py in 
28     TAGS = {}
29
---> 30 from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning
31 from warnings import warn
32

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'

Can someone please help me figure out how to fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have readed on internet and a solution may be:

```
$ pip install python-docx
#instead of pip install docx
```

(for python 3.x)
Please try this and tell me if works
Link: https://flutterq.com/solved-import-no-module-named-exceptions/

Comment: It's still not working, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried ```pip uninstall docx ; pip install python-docx``` ?

Comment: When I try to, it says, "WARNING: Skipping docx as it is not installed."

Comment: the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22765313/17453599, maybe there are some answers that works for you

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the most recent version of python-docx? (currently 0.8.11). I found that when I used 0.8.10 python couldn't find all the modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where python` command in cmd to find the path that python is installed in. then you can use this command -

```
[python path] -m pip install python-docx
```

Answer (score -2):

$ pip install python-docx

this worked for me.