# Detect paragraph break and put it in new variable in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, paragraph

I have a docx file, I opened it in PyCharm using textract. The docx contains a text with multiple paragraphs. What I want to do is detect every paragraph break and put every paragraph in a separate variables or as a list as string to use for later?

How can I do that in Python 3?

Please help!

I haven't anything on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `Document` from `docx`

```
from docx import Document
document = Document('path/to/your/file.docx')
paragraphs = [para.text for para in document.paragraphs]
```

Comment: Not working.

Getting this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test 1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from docx import Document
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\docx.py", line 30, in <module>
    from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'

Comment: Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765313/when-import-docx-in-python3-3-i-have-error-importerror-no-module-named-excepti